# Why won't my bus show up on Greyhound's live tracker website?

Tags: buses, greyhound

My fiancé is currently on a bus coming to where I am but every time I go to search for the bus on the tracker, it shows that there are no results.  I'm getting the schedule codes directly from his ticket so I'm not understanding why they aren't showing the bus.  its frustrating me because I'm worried he won't be able to make it to where I am from where he's getting dropped off if he gets here too late.

Comment: What do Greyhound customer services say?

Comment: Are you certain that you've read the ticket correctly?  Can you post an image of it (with any identifying information blacked out, of course).

Comment: Did your fiance board a different bus?

Answer (score 9):

It's hard to pinpoint the exact reason without more details. Here are some possible reasons.

**Broken onboard tracker**

If Greyhound doesn't have data from the tracker, for instance because it is broken, they will list the bus with this note:

> We're sorry, but the expected times of arrival of this bus are currently unavailable. Scheduled times are below.

**Different company operating the bus**

The bus may not actually be run by Greyhound, rather by a partner company. It should be noted on the ticket if the bus is run by a partner. Some partner bus companies have their own tracking sites where you can track the bus, for example:

- Jefferson Lines https://www.jeffersonlines.com/bus-tracker/
- Adirondack / Pine Hill / New York Trailways https://trailwaysny.com/?vh_other_services=wheres-my-bus

**Different country**

Depending on what country the bus travelling in, Greyhound has different tracking sites:

- http://bustracker.greyhound.com

  - Within the USA
  - Between the USA and Mexico
  - Within Mexico
  - Between the USA and Canada (or vice versa)
- http://bustracker.greyhound.ca

  - Entirely within Canada

Comment: Another possibility is that the tracking system on this particular bus is simply not working.

Answer (score 1):

There could be several reasons why your bus is not showing up on Greyhound's live tracker website:

Technical Issues: There might be a technical glitch in the system. The [live tracking system](https://greyhoundbustracker.info/) relies on GPS devices installed on the buses, and sometimes these devices can malfunction or lose signal, particularly in areas with poor reception.

Delay or Change in Schedule: If the bus is significantly delayed or if there has been a change in the schedule that has not been updated in the system, it might not show up on the live tracker.

Incorrect Information: Ensure you have entered the correct information for tracking. You may need the bus number, confirmation number, or other details to track the bus accurately.

Browser or App Issue: Sometimes the issue might be with the device or browser you are using. Try refreshing the page, using a different browser, or restarting the app.

Bus Not in Service: In rare cases, the bus might be canceled or not in service, and this information might not have been updated on the website yet.

If the bus is not showing up on the live tracker and you are concerned about your trip, it is recommended to contact Greyhound customer service or check for updates at the bus station.

Comment: GPS is a receive-only technology. It might be that the bus knows exactly where it is, but cannot communicate back out (via the on-board cellular modem) to tell the rest of the universe where it is.